# Filter on the_content ignores shortcodes

Tags: plugin-development, filters, shortcode

My function only affects the Page content and not the page content from the posts in page plugin which I call with a shortcode in the page.

**My plugin function**

```
add_filter('the_content', 'modify_tables', 10, 1);

function modify_tables($content) {

    //modifications...

    return $content;
} // function modify_tables
```

**My template code to ouput page**

```
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      the_content(); 
 endwhile;
```

Comment: How does the page plugin output its content? This is probably something you will need to ask of whomever wrote that plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Unmodified [`do_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) is effectively a filter on `the_content` with priority 11. Your filter has priority 10. So it runs before the shortcode is evaluated and it won't affect the post you put inside your page with a shortcode.

Now, you would think that the filter should also be triggered when the post inside the page is retrieved. This, however, is not necessarily true. The filter is only triggered when the content is retrieved with [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/), not with [`get_the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/).

Depending on what your modifications are, you may get the desired result if you set the priority on your filter to 99 or so, forcing the shortcode to be evaluated before the filter is applied.